# Using SPECIFICALLY reduce() to find the mode of a list of numbers

Tags: python

**PLEASE READ**: This is **NOT** a repeat question. I am asking how to specifically use reduce() to solve this problem.

I need to create a function that takes a list as a parameter and returns the mode. It needs to do this using the reduce() function from the functools library.

I have tried sorting the numbers first, then trying to solve this problem, but cannot understand how to do this still.

```py
from functools import reduce

#I believe the solution to this problem is something like this but it is missing something
def function(numbers)
    mode = reduce(lambda x,y: x if x == y else y, numbers)
    return mode
```

Comment: @abdusco do a browser search first: `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` are very much part of Python.

Comment: Common [homework question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069139/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-mode-of-a-list-using-reduce?noredirect=1)?

Comment: @Prune I understand map, filter, and reduce. I need to use the reduce method in order to solve this problem, and I am not sure how despite understanding how these functions work.

Comment: That comment was for a previous comment, claiming that `reduce` is not standard Python -- it would then need more description in your question.  Note the earlier version of the question: you have a colleague who has duplicated the question, but has no answer as of yet.

Comment: It's not clear what this limitations are on this. Does it need to *only* use `reduce()`? Does it need to only use a lambda? It's fairly easy to use reduce if you count the numbers first.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to harness the [Moore-Boyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm) algorithm, but it's guaranteed only if the mode is a majority.  Otherwise, a late element can come out on top, such as (0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6).

Comment: Using `reduce` on a `collections.Counter` object would be trivial.

Comment: That's my question @Prune. It's not clear if this is supposed to be easy or hard.

Comment: @ScottM But you are saying that you can use sorting.

Comment: @jdehesa You can sort the numbers using reduce I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

```
def get_mode(nums):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x if nums.count(x) > nums.count(y) else y, nums)
```

Comment: Ouch, maybe this is what the assignment is after, but it's painful to see something that should be an O(n) operation turned into a quadratic operation.

Answer (score 2):

Another version:

```
from functools import reduce

numbers = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]

def function(numbers):
    d = {}
    mode = reduce(lambda x, y: (lambda: [d.update([(x, d.get(x, 0)+1), ]), y])()[-1] if d.get(x, 0) < d.get(y, 0) else (lambda : [d.update([(y, d.get(y, 0)+1), ]), x])()[-1], numbers)
    return mode

print(function(numbers))
```

Prints:

```
6
```

Comment: Also prints one: `numbers = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way through sorting and iteration after that:

```
import random
from bisect import bisect  # Binary search algorithm

# Input data
random.seed(0)
a = [random.randint(1, 20) for _ in range(10000)]

# Sort
def reduce_sort_fn(s, i):
    # Insert the element at a point where it will be sorted
    s.insert(bisect(s, i), i)
    return s
a_sorted = reduce(reduce_sort_fn, a, [])

# Compute mode by sorting and tracking current element count and max element count
def reduce_mode_fn(t, i):
    (current_count, current_elem), max_t = t
    current_t = (current_count + 1 if i == current_elem else 1, i)
    return current_t, max(current_t, max_t)
mode = reduce(reduce_mode_fn, a_sorted, ((0, 0), (0, 0)))[1][1]
print(mode)
# 11

# Check result with counter
from collections import Counter
mode_counter = Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][0]
print(mode_counter)
# 11
```

Time complexity would be O(n^2) I think since even though binary search is used inserting in a list is O(n)... so wait maybe O(n^2 log(n)) actually? (in practice inserting in a list is actually quite fast) Memory would be O(n).

If you can also use dictionaries, you can just count like this:

```
def reduce_count_fn(d, i):
    # Insert the element at a point where it will be sorted
    d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
    return d
d = reduce(reduce_count_fn, a, {})
m = reduce(lambda a, b: a if a[1] > b[1] else b, d.items())[0]
```

Which would be O(n) in time and space.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't satisfied with the answers so I thought I'd think through the problem and help you get started on your homework ;)

First, think about how the reduce function is able of going through the iterator and looking at each pair of items.

Second, think about how you need to count how many identical things there are. So you need to sort your list before you use reduce on it.

Third, think about how you can keep track of comparing all these things outside of the function. Then you can count how many times you compared similar things, then add them to an external list, then take the max of that list.

Reference this program:

```
from functools import reduce

mylist = [1,1,3,7,3,3,3,2,7,1,3]
mylist.sort()
print(mylist)

def myfunction(x,y):
    global mylist
    if x==y:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("switch from " + str(x) + " to " + str(y))
    return y

reduce(myfunction,mylist)
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7]
yes
yes
switch from 1 to 2
switch from 2 to 3
yes
yes
yes
yes
switch from 3 to 7
yes
```

So now, think about what would happen if you added another global, maybe "mycount" at the top of the program and referenced it in your function. Every time you compare items and they are the same, you set the global mycount+=1. Then after your comparison fails, take the number and add it to a global list. When you finish, your maximum will be the number of times a mode occurred.

But if you want the item and the number of times it occurred, you will need to use a dictionary data structure.